# Analytical continuation of $F(p) = \sum_{n \neq 0, n \in \mathbb{Z}} \frac{e^{ipn}}{\sinh^2\kappa n}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to find out the behaviour of the series 
$$
F(p) = \sum_{n \neq 0, n \in \mathbb{Z}} \frac{e^{ipn}}{\sinh^2\kappa n}
$$
under analytical continuation in the complex $p$-plane ($\kappa$ is a positive constant). This series converges for all $p$ with $|$Im$(p)|<2\kappa$ and I have found a representation for this series in terms of Weierstrass elliptic functions. This representation shows that $F$ has poles at all points with Re$(p) = 2\pi k$ for $k\in \mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$ and Im$(p) = 2\kappa n$,  $n\in \mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$. As far as I understand the issue, around these points, non-trivial monodromy can exist, i.e. continuation around such poles could lead to a multi-valued function.

Performing explicit continuation using Taylor series seems to be unpractical, but I am not sure whether another approach exists. My question therefore is the following: how best to investigate the monodromy properties of this power series?

Comment: You have $\displaystyle F(p)=2\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\cos(pn)}{(\sinh(\kappa n))^2}$. Have you tried to expand $\displaystyle 2\frac{\cos(pn)}{(\sinh(\kappa n))^2}=\frac{2^{3}\exp(-2\kappa n)\cos(pn)}{(1-\exp(-2\kappa n))^2}$ using $\displaystyle \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=\sum (m+1)x^m$ (putting $x=\exp(-2\kappa n)$ and exchanging the summations ?

Comment: I did not use this trick to find an expansion of the series, but used another method to find an expression in terms of Weierstrass functions. From your method, I cannot deduce anything about behaviour around poles away from zero, can I? I just don't see how. Btw, this is what I found using your method:$$ \sum_{m=2}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 8 \cos (pn) m e^{-2\kappa n m }$$

Comment: Well, I have perhaps made a mistake, but putting $q=\exp(-2\kappa)$ and $\displaystyle G(z)=\sum_{m\geq 1}mq^m\frac{z-q^m}{1-2zq^m+q^{2m}}$, I have found $F(p)=8G(\cos(p))$.

Comment: That does not look good to me, since originally the cos-term contained an $n$, which has dissapeared in your expression, while I don't know summation identities that could lead to this. However, it might still be correct. But ultimately, I don't see how this will help me. Could you tell me what would be the use of having the expression $G$? As I said, I already have a closed expression for $F$ in an open nhood of the real line, which is valid on $\mathbb{C}$ except for some poles. I just want to know if it is the unique analytical continuation of $F$.

Comment: Sorry, I mean of course, that I have an expression which coincides with $F$ on an open nhood of the real line and extends as a meromorphic function on the whole complex plane.

Comment: I think that  $ \sum_{m=2}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 8 \cos (pn) m e^{-2\kappa n m }$ is the same that I have (with $m\geq 1$).Write $2\cos(pn)=\exp(ipn)+\exp(-ipn)$, and sum in $n$. If my expression is true, let $R>1$, and $\Omega_R$ the subset of $p$ such that $|\exp(\pm ip)|<R$. There is an $M$, such that $ 8\sum_{m\geq M+1}mq^m\frac{\cos(p)-q^{m}}{1-2q^m\cos(p)+q^{2m}}$ is analytic on $\Omega_R$. Hence you have  $F(p)=S(\cos(p))+g_R(p)$ for $p$ in an open subset of the real line, and $S\in \mathbb{C}(x)$, $g_R$ analytic on $\Omega_R$. But it seems that you have already that.

Comment: Correction: "for p in an open subset of the real line" $\to$ "for p in an open nhood of the real line"

Comment: It seems our two summations do coincide:) Yes, I already have such an expression which is analytic in your $\Omega_R$ with $R = 2\kappa$. My question is only whether there exists a unique analytic continuation from $\Omega_R$ to the whole of $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I think (but verify, I can be wrong...) that this prove your assertion: Let $R_0>1$ such that we are sure that in my notations $F(p)=8G(\cos(p))$ for $p\in \Omega_{R_0}$. Now let $R$ large, $S=P/Q$, $P,Q$ polynomials. In $\Omega_{R_0}$ we have $Q(\cos(p))F(p)=P(\cos(p))+Q(\cos(p))g_R(p)=H(p)$. As $H(p)$ is analytic in $\Omega_R$, this is the analytic continuation of $Q(\cos(p))F(p)$ in $\Omega_R$, hence $F(p)=8G(\cos(p))$ is the unique meromorphic continuation of $F(p)$ in $\Omega_R$. As we can take $R$ arbitrary large, we are done.

Comment: I think that, the technicalities aside, what your argument boils down to is the following: we have a series $F$ which converges in a finite neighbourhood of the real line. We find (by some means) a function which coincides with $F$ in this neighbourhood and is meromorphic on the whole complex plane. From this you conclude that this is the unique analytic continuation of $F$. For me this is still not obvious: I know that analytic continuations are unique if the functions involved are holomorphic, but this also hold for meromorphic functions? Could you refer me to a proof of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I try to answer. As this is too long, I do not use "comment" but "answer". Note that your question is not easy, so you must verify.

We have a function defined in a nhood of the real line, $F(p)$, and we have for this function a first meromorphic continuation as a meromorphic function on all $\mathbb{C}$, say it is $M(z)$. So $M(z)$ is, on a disk $B(0,\rho)$, with $\rho$ small, analytic and equal to $F$. Suppose that there exists another meromorphic continuation, on $\mathbb{C}$ say $N(z)$, and also $N$ is analytic and equal to $F$ on $B(0,\rho)$ (Hence $M$=$N$ on $B(0,\rho)$). If $N$ is not equal to $M$, this imply that there exist $t\in \mathbb{C}$, that we can suppose not to be a pole of $N$ or $M$, such that $N(t) \not =M(t)$.

Now we can find  $U=B(0,R)$ with $R$ large, containing $B(0,\rho)$ and $t$. The functions  $M$ and $N$ have a finite number of poles in $U$. Let $A$, $B$ be polynomials such that $A(t)B(t)$ is non zero, and $A(z)M(z)$, $B(z)N(z)$ analytic in $U$. Then $A(z)B(z)M(z)$ and $A(z)B(z)N(z)$ are analytic in $U$, and they are equal on $B(0,\rho)$. Hence they are equal on $U$. But then we can put $z=t$, and this gives $M(t)=N(t)$, a contradiction.

Comment: You just beat me to it and I like your answer. It shows clearly why the continuation must be unique. Since it is as of yet not a complete answer to my original question, I will wait with accepting it.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer is nice too. I have found that this was a very interesting exchange. Best regards. (Attention at your function $G$ in your answer, a factor $m\exp(-2\kappa m)$ must be added).

Comment: And thanks to you! It was very illuminating for me:) Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the discussion with Kelenner, I believe I can answer my own question:

We have a function $F$, which is given by a convergent series for $|$Im$(p)| <2\kappa$ (call this open neighbourhood of the real line $\Omega$). By rewriting, one can show that $F(p) = G(\cos(p))$ where 
$$
G(z) = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}e^{-2\kappa m} \frac{z-e^{-2\kappa m}}{1-z e^{-2\kappa m} +e^{-4\kappa m}}.
$$
the partial sums of this series converge uniformly to $G$ is we restrict the domain of $G$ to the set $\cos(\Omega)$, we find that $G$ is analytic on this set as the uniform limit of analytic functions. Moreover, $F$ is analytic as the composition of analytic functions. Consider now the subset $V \subset \mathbb{C}$ being the entire complex plane without the poles mentioned in the question. This set is open and there exists a function $F_e$ given by 
$$
F_e(p) = \wp\left( r_p\right) + \left( \zeta(r_p) - \frac{2r_p}{\omega}\zeta\left(\frac{\omega}{2}\right) \right) \frac{\wp''(r_p)}{\wp'(r_p)}+ 2\left( \zeta(r_p) - \frac{2r_p}{\omega}\zeta\left(\frac{\omega}{2}\right) \right)^2,
$$
where $r_p = \frac{ip}{4\kappa}$, $\wp$ is the Weierstrass elliptic function, $\zeta$ is the Weierstrass $\zeta$-function and both are defined on the lattice (1,$\omega$). This function is holomorphic on $V$ and equal to $F$ on $\Omega$. Therefore, it is the unique analytic continuation of $F$ to $V$ ([see proof here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Uniqueness_of_Analytic_Continuation)). We cannot extend $F$ any further, since its analytic continuation shows that it is not finite at any of the unincluded points of $\mathbb{C}$.